# Linear Operator $A$ and $B$ bounded if $(Ax,y) = (x,By)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $A,B$ are linear operators on Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$, satisfy
$$ (Ax,y) = (x,By) $$
for $\forall x,y \in \mathcal{H}$. Show that $A,B$ are bounded.

---

What I can get so far : $A,B$ are almost 'adjoint', except that we don't know yet if they are bounded.

Thanks for helping.